# Significado de (void *)

Tags: c, tipagem

Qual o significado de chamar uma função com uma que era `int` e é passada como `(void *)`?

Se a variável foi declarada como `int` porque se passa ela como parâmetro para uma função
`*(void *)variavel*` ?

Exemplo

```
int var = 10;

teste((void *)var);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O `(void *)` quer dizer que é um ponteiro para uma variável não especificando o tipo da variável.

Por exemplo, pode-se ter o mesmo conceito com `(int *)` onde é um ponteiro para uma variável do tipo `int`, especificando o tipo.

A Microsoft tem um documento explicando um pouco isso em [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)