# Na prática, qual a utilidade dos ponteiros em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Faz pouco tempo que estou estudando a linguagem e até agora não identifiquei utilidade prática para a utilização de ponteiros. Eu entendo o seu funcionamento bem por alto, porém nada mais.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Essencialmente serve para criar [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101). O que pode ser muito importante para resolver vários problemas da computação, conforme a resposta *linkada*.

Então em vez de acessar um valor diretamente, você passa ter um endereço onde tem esse valor. O valor pode ser muito coisa, pode até mesmo [não ser identificado o que é de antemão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16474/101), o que gera flexibilidade, e uma certa insegurança, claro.

## *Array*

Um dos usos mais comuns é indicar onde tem uma determinada informação em uma sequência, ou seja é uma forma de criar algo [como um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Então o índice desse *array* na prática é um endereço de memória, ou seja é uma forma de apontar para o local onde está o valor que deseja. Um `a[2]` por exemplo, é onde está iniciando o *array*, endereço guardado em `a` e o 2 é o deslocamento que precisa fazer a partir daquele ponto, então o endereço que ele acessa de fato é [`a + (2 * sizeof(int))`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2717/101) se o tipo desse *array* for um `int`.

A própria *string* é um *array* de caracteres. Então o tipo de uma *string* é [`char *`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101), ou seja um ponteiro para caracteres.

## *Heap*

Existem diversos casos que alocar a memória na *stack* não atende as necessidades (não vem ao caso falar aqui) e depois de alocar no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) precisa ter uma forma de acessar esse [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), a forma de fazer isso é usar um ponteiro para esse objeto.

Na prática há ponteiros opacos mesmo para a *stack*, é que não precisa lidar com eles em seu código salvo em situações específicas.

## Parâmetro

Outro grande uso é passar um argumento para uma função quando na verdade você não quer copiar o dado, seja porque ele é grande ou porque o que for mudado nele deve refletir no local original, então no lugar de passar o dado você passa o endereço onde ele está, isso é um ponteiro. Costuma-se chamar de [passar por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/101), porque você passa algo que refere o objeto real e não uma cópia do objeto que seria o normal por padrão ([referência X ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)).

## Função anônima

O valor de um [ponteiro pode ser o endereço do código de uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2983/101), assim pode trocar a função a ser executada baseado no valor do ponteiro, ou seja, pode anonimizar a função.

Aliás, o [endereço de uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101) não deixa de ser um ponteiro, mas em C não aparece no código. Na prática a função como usamos só existe porque existe o ponteiro.

## *Array* heterogêneo

Pode ter um [ponteiro de ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92823/101). Junto com o `void *` pode resolver um problema de *array* heterogêneo. Quando não sabe o tamanho de cada elemento do *array* e ele pode variar, cria um *array* de ponteiros que apontarão para os elementos em outro lugar, assim mantêm homogeneidade de tamanho de cada elemento exigido pelo *array*.

Não precisa ser só um *array*. Qualquer estrutura que precisa saber o tamanho e não se sabe até usar. Você delega o objeto que não se sabe o tamanho para outro lugar, aí a sua estrutura que precisa saber o tamanho pode ter o tamanho fixo porque o objeto que varia saiu de lá e só tem um ponteiro para esse objeto e o ponteiro tem tamanho conhecido.

Na prática só *array* podem ter seu tamanho não conhecido pelo compilador, qualquer outra estrutura que não seja um *array*, de uma forma ou de outra, precisa do tamanho conhecido.

I *array* não precisa saber o tamanho total, mas o tamanho do elemento precisa, afinal ele acessa o elemento com complexidade O(1), portanto constante, então tem que ser acessado com matemática pura e isso só é possível se o tamanho de todos elementos é o mesmo.

## Outros

A partir daí pode-se compor o ponteiro de diversas formas e obter mecanismos bem mais sofisticados.

Por exemplo, em linguagens de mais alto nível orientadas a objeto usa-se [ponteiro para o objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161846/101). E também para poder escolher que método usar baseado no objeto real ([polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101)). Tudo isso pode ser feito em C, mas você tem que fazer na mão.

O fato de algumas linguagens não permitirem o programador acessar um ponteiro não quer dizer que não o tenha, ele está lá escondido de você. C apenas o expõe sempre (ou quase).

Um exemplo de estrutura de dados que só é viável com ponteiro é a [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101). O mesmo vale para uma [árvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101). A única forma de indicar onde está o elemento a seguir é com um ponteiro.

Além de exemplos de programas triviais o ponteiro sempre é usado em códigos.

Existem operadores para [pegar um endereço de um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) e para [pegar o valor do endereço referenciado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101).

Veja mais:

- [Didática simples de Ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26633/101)
- [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101)
- [Por que consigo acessar uma estrutura sem ser pelo ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105224/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Ponteiros existem em qualquer linguagem, a diferença é que em C eles são explícitos, e em outras liguagens eles geralmente não o são.

Quando você declara um objeto em JavaScript por exemplo você está usando um ponteiro:

```
var obj = { "nome": "Thiago" };
```

Se você passar obj para uma função, e a função alterar alguma propriedade de obj, o objeto original é alterado. Isso porque obj é passado "por referência" para a função, e referência nada mais é do que um ponteiro.

Em C você pode passar o ponteiro para uma struct, o que permite uma função alterar os valores da struct, mas você também pode passar a struct "por cópia" o que não envolve ponteiros, mas acarreta em literalmente copiar todo o conteúdo de memória da struct. Quando você passa uma struct "por cópia" à uma função, a struct original é preservada, ou seja, alterar os valores da struct na função não vai afetar os valores da struct original.

A maioria das linguagens suporta apenas a passagem de valores "por cópia" para tipos primitivos (int, boolean, float, etc.).

Comment: Normalmente, linguagens que não suportam ponteiros usam-se de **referência**. A diferença entre ponteiro e referência são as operações que cada tipo de dado suporta, com ponteiro normalmente tendo aritmética de ponteiro e qualquer variável tendo a possibilidade de se pegar seu "ponteiro correspondente" (`&var` em C). Referências normalmente não tem essas operações. Outra coisa, em Bash, a referência é obtida usando expansão de variável `${!var}` para pegar conteúdo armazenado na variável que tem nome armazenado em `$var`, porém não é fácil retornar o valor por parâmetro passado por referência

Comment: Verdade, Jefferson, eu acabei simplificando demais.

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala pode dar uma editada na resposta caso pense ter simplificado demais

Answer (score 0):

Em C, você não possui suporte para alguns tipos de dados complexos, como uma string por exemplo. Também não há como passar uma variável "por referência" a uma função. É aí que você tem que usar ponteiros. Além disso, você pode fazer com que eles indiquem praticamente qualquer coisa, listas encadeadas, struct e assim por diante.

Os ponteiros devem ser usados onde não existe outra opção, por falta de uma funcionalidade adequada, ou apenas por questões de desempenho, caso julgar isso um fator determinante na sua aplicação, pois você tem o acesso direto a memória do computador.

Comment: Estruturas você não considera complexo? E os números complexos?, previstos na biblioteca padrão?

Comment: Faltou "alguns" naquele parágrafo, e acabou descontextualizando, vou corrigir, obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: Tenho algumas discordâncias quanto ao uso dos ponteiros, mas minhas discordâncias não invalidam sua resposta