# Por que usar um ponteiro nesse algoritmo?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, classificação

Quando retiro o código não funciona. Por que?

E por que o algoritmo de *insertion sort* é apropriado apenas para lista de pequenas entradas, tipo *array* e *list* (pequena)?

```
 void insert_sort(int *vetor, int TAM){
     int i, j, aux;
     for(i = 1; i < TAM; i++){
         aux = vetor[i];
         for(j = i; (j > 0) && (aux < vetor[j - 1]); j--)
             vetor[j] = vetor[j - 1];
         vetor[j] = aux;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Eu respondi a outra pergunta, mas não devia, se é outra pergunta, faça separado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você quer classificar uma sequencia de valores, certo? Se passar um `int` está passando só um valor.

Se criar uma sequência de valores em algum lugar pode só passar o endereço de onde está esta sequência e o algoritmo pode acessar esses valores e fazer o que ele precisa em cada um dos elementos.

Pode estar perguntando porque não passar a sequência toda. Provavelmente ela é muito grande para copiar tudo de um lugar para outro, o que não tem necessidade alguma de fazer isto.

Tem uma [pergunta que fala sobre o uso prático do ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244828/101).

O principal problema do algoritmo de classificação por inserção é que ele tem complexidade quadrática (O(n<sup>2</sup>)) no pior caso. Então para apenas 1000 elementos em ordem reversa ele tem que fazer 1 milhão de operações de cópias de dados, isto é trágico. Mas em pequenos volumes isto não é impactante e por manter localidade de referência o cache é muito mais eficiente e pode ser mais rápido do que algoritmos que fazem menos cópias mas precisam comparar mais ou que as comparações custam mais, ou que precisam de mais memória.

Comment: Dúvida esclarecida quanto ao uso do ponteiro e a complexidade. Thanks !