# Dúvidas sobre pilha dinâmica - C

Tags: c, stack

(1)Criar um ponteiro do tipo NO dentro da struct NO não implica que dentro desse ponteiro haverá outro ponteiro do tipo NO que terá outro e assim por diante?

```
typedef struct NO{
    int dado;
    struct NO *prox;
}NO
```

(2)Os ponteiro do tipo NO armazenam dentro de si mesmo algo? Eles não são só o nome da estrutura que declaramos? Não seria o que está dentro da estrutura que armazenaria?

```
    ptr->prox = p->topo;  
    p->topo = ptr;
```

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct NO{
    int dado;
    struct NO *prox;
}NO;

typedef struct PILHA{
    NO *topo;
}PILHA;

void inicializarPilha(PILHA *p){
    p->topo = NULL;
}

void empilha(int dado, PILHA *p){
    NO *ptr = (NO*) malloc(sizeof(NO));
    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("ERRO");
    }else{
        ptr->dado = dado;
        ptr->prox = p->topo;  
        p->topo = ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Na prática, qual a utilidade dos ponteiros em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244828/na-pr%c3%a1tica-qual-a-utilidade-dos-ponteiros-em-c)

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct NO{
    int dado;
    struct NO *prox;
}NO
```

> (1) Criar um ponteiro do tipo NO dentro da struct NO não implica que dentro desse ponteiro haverá outro ponteiro do tipo NO que terá outro e assim por diante?

Não.

Sobre a nomenclatura disso: não é um *"ponteiro do tipo NO"*. `prox` é `struct NO*`, um ponteiro para uma `struct NO`. Esse ponteiro aponta para uma área de tamanho `sizeof(struct NO*)` e nada se pode dizer sobre seu conteúdo já que nada foi alocado ou inicializado.

> (2) Os ponteiro do tipo NO armazenam dentro de si mesmo algo? Eles não são só o nome da estrutura que declaramos? Não seria o que está dentro da estrutura que armazenaria?

Não são *"ponteiros do tipo NO"* mas sim ponteiros para estruturas `NO`. Podem armazenar qualquer coisa, é apenas um endereço de uma área de memória. Mas por construção vai armazenar um endereço de uma `struct NO` como declarado, ou `NULL` por segurança.

#### Ligeiramente off-topic

Em seu código talvez devesse usar um outro nome para a tal `struct` apenas para a referência interna, algo assim:

```
typedef struct st_no
{
    int           dado;
    struct st_no* prev;

} Node;
```

E usar `Node` em toda a parte.

E no caso da pilha talvez fosse mais expressivo chamar o ponteiro de `prev` e não de `prox`.

Em geral a convenção de nomenclatura em `C` é usar apenas a primeira letra em maiúsculas para `structs` e reservar nomes com **todas** maiúsculas para `#define` de constantes. E não se usa *camelCase* como em java mas sim um único `_` separando as palavras. Questão de preferência pessoal e da definição de onde trabalhe ou estude, mas de longe é mais comum como estou dizendo.

Em relação à pilha é quase universal usar PUSH POP e TOP para as funções.

### EXEMPLO

Um exemplo de uma maneira comum de escrever isso em `C` e que pode achar útil

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_no
{
    int           dado;
    struct st_no* prev;

} Node;

typedef struct Pilha
{
    Node*  topo;
    size_t size;

} Pilha;

int    POP(Pilha*);
int    PUSH(int, Pilha*);
int*   TOP(Pilha*);
Pilha* destruir_pilha(Pilha*);
Pilha* inicializar_pilha();
int    testar_pilha(Pilha* const, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Pilha* tst = inicializar_pilha();
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tpilha vazia: ");
    tst = destruir_pilha(tst);

    // agora cria e coloca de 10 a 1 na pilha
    tst = inicializar_pilha();
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i -= 1) PUSH(i, tst);
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tinseridos 10..1\n");

    int* topo = TOP(tst);
    printf("Topo: %d\n", *topo);
    free(topo);
    POP(tst);
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tRemovido TOP\n");

    tst = destruir_pilha(tst);
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tVazia de novo\n"); // nao vai sair
    return 0;
}

Pilha* destruir_pilha(Pilha* pilha)
{
    Node* temp = NULL;
    if (pilha == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("destruir_pilha(): %llu elementos\n", pilha->size);
    while (pilha->size > 0) POP(pilha);
    free(pilha);  // apaga a pilha afinal
    return NULL;
}

Pilha* inicializar_pilha()
{
    Pilha* p = (Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("inicializar_pilha()\n");
    p->size = 0;
    p->topo = NULL;
    return p;
}

int POP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (p->size == 0) return 0;
    printf("POP(%d)\n", p->topo->dado);
    Node* temp = (Node*) p->topo->prev;  // salva esse
    free(p->topo);
    p->topo = temp;  // restaura
    p->size -= 1;    // desconta 1
    return 0;
}

int PUSH(int d, Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;  // sem pilha
    Node* ptr = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (ptr == NULL) return -2;
    printf("PUSH(%d)\n", d);
    ptr->dado = d;
    ptr->prev = p->topo;

    p->topo   = ptr;
    p->size += 1; // conta +1
    return 0;
}

int* TOP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return NULL;  // sem pilha
    int* top = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (top == NULL) return NULL;
    *top = p->topo->dado;
    return top;
}

int testar_pilha(Pilha* const pilha, const char* tit)
{
    if (pilha == NULL) return -1;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s", tit);
    if (pilha->size == 0)
    {
        printf("\tPilha VAZIA\n\n\t--\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\t%llu elementos na Pilha:\n\n\t", pilha->size);
    if (pilha->size == 0) return 0;
    Node* p = pilha->topo;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pilha->size - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", p->dado);
        p = p->prev;
    }
    printf("%d\n\n\t--\n", p->dado);
    return (int) pilha->size;
}
```

#### saída desse exemplo

```
inicializar_pilha()
        pilha vazia:    Pilha VAZIA

        --
destruir_pilha(): 0 elementos
inicializar_pilha()
PUSH(10)
PUSH(9)
PUSH(8)
PUSH(7)
PUSH(6)
PUSH(5)
PUSH(4)
PUSH(3)
PUSH(2)
PUSH(1)
        inseridos 10..1
        10 elementos na Pilha:

        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

        --
Topo: 1
POP(1)
        Removido TOP
        9 elementos na Pilha:

        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

        --
destruir_pilha(): 9 elementos
POP(2)
POP(3)
POP(4)
POP(5)
POP(6)
POP(7)
POP(8)
POP(9)
POP(10)
```

Porque escrever assim?

Veja esse trecho por exemplo:

```
    Pilha* tst = inicializar_pilha();
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tpilha vazia: ");
    tst = destruir_pilha(tst);
```

- retornando os endereços de pilhas diretamente fica mais simples de ler o código e invalidar o ponteiro ao destruir a pilha, assim nunca vai ter um ponteiro inválido perdido.
- colocar o tamanho da pilha DENTRO da pilha é sempre conveniente, afinal a pilha é um container
- com o tamanho dentro da pilha apagar uma pilha pode usar POP() diretamente:

```
Pilha* destruir_pilha(Pilha* pilha)
{
    Node* temp = NULL;
    if (pilha == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("destruir_pilha(): %llu elementos\n", pilha->size);
    while (pilha->size > 0) POP(pilha);
    free(pilha);  // apaga a pilha afinal
    return NULL;
}
```

e é muito mais legível e seguro.

- uma função para testar a pilha e que aceita um título é muito conveniente porque se pode escrever testes simples sem esforço, por exemplo

```
    // agora cria e coloca de 10 a 1 na pilha
    tst = inicializar_pilha();
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i -= 1) PUSH(i, tst);
    testar_pilha(tst, "\tinseridos 10..1\n");
```

Nota: sempre uso cast no retorno de `malloc()` por uma questão de documentação. Programas complexos podem alocar várias estruturas em seguida e ajuda ao desenvolvedor poder se certificar do que é a alocação lendo o cast que seria implícito. A noção de que isso (o cast) é ruim vem dos anos '90 dos tempos da usenet. Está no folclórico C-Faq que não é atualizado desde os 90 e hoje em dia se sabe que coisas implícitas em geral não são boas, E esse é o caso do cast. Só para referência, um dos motivos para não usar o cast seria para ajudar o programador a não esquecer o `include` de `stlib.h`. Genial. Está lá no tal FAQ. Favor não me lembrar disso.

[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/566964/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-pilha-din%C3%A2mica-c[post]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/566964/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-pilha-din%C3%A2mica-c%5Bpost%5D)

Comment: :) E dessa vez levou pouco mais de 1 hora para uma resposta minha ser marcada como inútil! Mas é bom pra eu lembrar que preciso melhorar! Eu respondi às 2 perguntas do autor, juntei um código de exemplo com considera;coes de como resolver o problema e incluí a saída do programa exemplo e mais alguma discussão sobre o caso. Pena não ser sufciente ainda para ser útil ao menos. Espero melhorar! :)

Comment: Muito obrigado!